# Click event is missing when a button is too small

Tags: css, tinymce

I've created an angular directive for a tinyMce where on setup I add 2 handlers: for a blur event to hide a toolbar and for a click event to show it. Also I've created another directive where I have a textarea and a button. On button click I want a toolbar disappear  and some action occur.

```
 <body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
    app.controller("MyCntrl", function ($scope) {

    }).directive("myDirective", function ( $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, elem) {
                scope.click = function () {
                    console.log("click");
                };
            },
            template: "<textarea data-tm ></textarea><button ng-click='click()' style='width:200px; height: 74px;' id='btn'>click</button>"

        }
    }).directive("tm", function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    tinymce.init({
                        mode: 'textareas',
                        setup: function (ed) {
                            ed.on('blur', function (e) {
                                ed.theme.panel.find("toolbar").hide();
                                console.log("blur");
                            });
                            ed.on('click', function (e) {
                                ed.theme.panel.find("toolbar").show();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });                   
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Link to the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/aZRzsgaiiQqLMv0EnYLG?p=preview)

If I click inside of a textarea and then on a button the following happens:
when the button's height is relatively small, for example 20px, only blur event occurs, but when the height is relatively big let's say  120px both blur and click events occur.

Could you tell me why is that? My guess is that in the first case the button is overlapped by something but I cannot find but what.

Thanks

**Update**: It seems like a problem with tinyMCE. I've remove angular and created just a tinyMce editor and a button underneath. The same problem: doesn't work when a button is too small and works either if a button is enough big or placed above the editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    mode: 'textareas',
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('blur', function (e) {
            ed.theme.panel.find("toolbar").hide();
            console.log("blur");
        });
        ed.on('click', function (e) {
            ed.theme.panel.find("toolbar").show();
        });
    }
});

function myFunction() {
    console.log("click");
}

</script>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" style="height:100px;">click</button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9W2I5rzt0hVb6bi1a91?p=preview)

Comment: Seems to work for me.  What browser are you having an issue in?

Comment: Chrome, IE11, Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we click on the button a toolbar becomes hidden and the button moves up so when the mouse released it's not over the same object. Mousedown event could be used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a little timeout, so the button will stay in it's position during the click event:

```
$timeout(function() { ed.theme.panel.find("toolbar").hide() }, 100);
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGeDhkEiK9n5mUKJGBSY?p=preview)

Comment: If you remove a style for the button the problem stays. See http://plnkr.co/edit/Kl6XPt85FM7TCrDlDg1A?p=preview